# QWT zoomer plus panner with continuous replot

Tags: plot, zooming, pan, qwt

I have some experience with QWT doing some small test programs, but now I need to make something that is professional.

I have a plot where I need to do zooming and panning.  I install a zoomer which works great and add a panner, but when I pan the zoomed area the replot works fine at the end of the panning, but during the movement I just have the image from the last replot which moves around and on the sides I have blank images.  Is there anyway that I can have it display a continual updating image while it moves (something like goggle maps)?  I realize that google maps is just a jpg image so it is not the same, but it would look much cleaner if I could do this.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This might work...

```
class CustomPanner: public QwtPlotPanner
{

public:
    explicit CustomPanner(QWidget* parent) : QwtPlotPanner(parent){}

virtual bool eventFilter( QObject * object, QEvent * event)
{
    if ( object == NULL || object != parentWidget() )
            return false;

    switch ( event->type() )
    {
        case QEvent::MouseButtonPress:
        {
            widgetMousePressEvent( static_cast<QMouseEvent *>( event ) );
            break;
        }
        case QEvent::MouseMove:
        {
            QMouseEvent * evr = static_cast<QMouseEvent *>( event );
            widgetMouseMoveEvent( evr );
            widgetMouseReleaseEvent( evr  );
            setMouseButton(evr->button(), evr->modifiers());
            widgetMousePressEvent( evr);
            break;
        }
        case QEvent::MouseButtonRelease:
        {
            QMouseEvent * evr = static_cast<QMouseEvent *>( event );
            widgetMouseReleaseEvent( static_cast<QMouseEvent *>( event ) );
            break;
            grab();
        }
        case QEvent::KeyPress:
        {
            widgetKeyPressEvent( static_cast<QKeyEvent *>( event ) );
            break;
        }
        case QEvent::KeyRelease:
        {
            widgetKeyReleaseEvent( static_cast<QKeyEvent *>( event ) );
            break;
        }
        case QEvent::Paint:
        {
            if ( isVisible() )
                return true;
            break;
        }
        default:;
    }

    return false;
   }
};
```

Now use tihs instead of PlotPanner

Comment: It works beautifully.  Of course, I had to adapt the code to my situation.  They should make one like this the default for qwt.  It was designed in a day of much slower computers.  It's still a great code base, but we can spare the cpu for the better redrawing these days.